# Compare amounts of two fields and compare it with third filed and return the result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have an scenario where I need to compare amounts based on their Code type and compare that amount with another code type and return the result.

For example:

```
SELECT distinct P.TERM_KEY, C.Country_code, Amt.DAMT
FROM TERM P
      INNER JOIN Country C ON P.TERM_KEY= C.TERM_KEY 
      INNER JOIN Amount Amt ON C.COU_KEY = Amt.PARENT_KEY AND Amt.PARENT_TABLE=Country
WHERE P.Term_no = 'ABCD' AND C.Country_CD IN (50, 51)
```

and result of this query is below:

```
    TERM_KEY        Country_code     DAMT
    201000000085    5000             1000.00
    201000000083    5001             750.00
    201000000081    5001             1000.00
    201000000342    5000             1000.00
    201000002340    5001             750.00
    201000034733    5001             1000.00
```

Now I need to compare the Damt of country codes (50 and 51) with Country code 20, if Damt of country code 20 and Country Codes (50 , 51) are equal I need to report value as '5869', else if not equal I need to report value as '0000'.

I'll use the above result set in some other case condition

Example

```
Case  
WHEN C.County = 999 and C.Contry_code = '20' AND ISNULL(CDED.DAmt,0)=0 THEN '5869'  
  C.County = 999 and C.Contry_code = '20' AND ISNULL(Amt.DAmt,0)!=0 THEN '0000'
end as Country_County
```

So CDED has to return the result set which I need to use in case. How can that be done?

Comment: Which DMBS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your data looks like or how it's related, but i would just create 2 sub-queries and join them.

```
select  case 
            when ISNULL(subset_5051.DAmt,0) = ISNULL(subset_20.DAmt,0) then '5869'
            else '0000'
        end
from
    (
        SELECT distinct P.TERM_KEY, C.Country_code, Amt.DAMT
        FROM TERM P
              INNER JOIN Country C ON P.TERM_KEY= C.TERM_KEY 
              INNER JOIN Amount Amt ON C.COU_KEY = Amt.PARENT_KEY AND Amt.PARENT_TABLE=Country
        WHERE P.Term_no = 'ABCD' AND C.Country_CD IN (50, 51) 
    ) as subset_5051

    [left / right / inner / full] join

    (
        SELECT distinct P.TERM_KEY, C.Country_code, Amt.DAMT
        FROM TERM P
              INNER JOIN Country C ON P.TERM_KEY= C.TERM_KEY 
              INNER JOIN Amount Amt ON C.COU_KEY = Amt.PARENT_KEY AND Amt.PARENT_TABLE=Country
        WHERE P.Term_no = 'ABCD' AND C.Country_CD IN (20) 
    ) as subset_20
    on subset_5051.[?] =  subset_20.[?]
```

i don't know what type of join you should use, or what columns to join on, but that should get you started.